# How do you rotate buttons on a ToolBar?

Tags: objective-c

I have 3 views in my app.  Two are in portrait, and one is in landscape. I have a toolbar at the top on the main view that displays in each subview.  On the landscape view, I can rotate the tool bar to get it on the top of the "rotated" landscape view, but I can't get the buttons on the toolbar to rotate.  Any ideas?

Comment: You would normally put a navigation bar, not a toolbar, at the top of the screen in iOS.